# What's the complexity of these three for loops?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

Having:

- input array `A[1...n]`
- `N` length of `A`

Algorithm:

```
for(int i=N; i>0; i--) { // Loop 1
    for(int j=1; j<N; j=j*2) { // Loop 2
        for(int k=0; k<j; k++) { // Loop 3
            // constant number of operations
        }
    }
}
```

I know that loop `1` has `O(N)` time complexity.

For loop `2` I would say that the time complexity is `O(logN)`.

What's the complexity for loop and `3` (and `2` if I'm wrong) and for the algorithm?

Comment: Actually your complexity is O(N * log^2 N). You are right with the second loop complexity and the third it's identic

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**O(N^2)**

Because of the interdependency of `j` and `k` (at `k<j`) you can't consider loop2 and loop3 separately.  Let `N=2^m`, for simplicity of calculation.  So, `j` will be 1, 2, 4, ..., 2^(m-1), and loop3 executes `j` times each time it is reached.  So the combined loop2 and loop3 executes

```
  1   + 2   + 4   + ... + 2^(m-1)
= 2^0 + 2^1 + 2^2 + ... + 2^(m-1)
```

This is a [Geometric Progression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression), and is equal to `2^m - 1 = N - 1`, which is O(N).  Now throwing in loop1, O(N), and we get O(N^2).

Edit:

Here is the perl code I ran to test this

```
print "N\tExpected\tCounted\n";

for my $N (10, 100, 1024, 8192)
{
    my $count = 0;
    for(my $i=$N; $i>0; $i--)
    {
        for(my $j=1; $j<$N; $j*=2)
        {
            for(my $k=0; $k<$j; $k++)
            {
                $count++;
            }
        }
    }
    my $expected_count = $N*$N - $N;
    print "$N\t$expected_count\t$count\n";
}
```

And the output:

```
N       Expected        Counted
10      90              150
100     9900            12700
1024    1047552         1047552
8192    67100672        67100672
```

Note that we don't hit the expected exactly unless `N=2^m`.

Comment: So you're saying it's not `O(nlognn)` ?

Comment: Correct.  I am saying that it is faster than that.

Answer (score 0):

For k, the loop executes 2, 4, ..., N or N-1 times, depending on whether N is even or odd, so the time complexity for the three loops is O(n*logn*n).

Edit: Thanks for  Degustaf. I messed it up and have found that the `k` loop is dependent on the `j` loop, so the time complexity of for(j) loop is max(O(n),O(logn)) = O(n).

Edit Again: Consider the `j` loop and the `k` loop as a whole, it executes 2+4+...+N times, and the number of items is logN. 
The time complexity for the `j` loop and the `k` loop is what Degustaf writes: O(N).

The reason why I think max(O(n), O(logn)): When reaching the point where `k` loop executes N times, the for `j` loop has executed logN-1 times. During previous executions, the execution time of `k` can be considered great smaller, like a constant like N/2, N/4.., 2. So the last N-times `k` loop is considered as executing after the `j` loop has executed for (logN-1) times.

Comment: @sereneL Please edit your answer to reflect the correct running time, or delete the answer (which currently doesn't add any value beyond Degustaf's answer).