# Someone help explain this BigO complexity of this code, two parts really confuses me

Tags: big-o

```
     for ( i = 1, i<n; i * = 2) {
          for ( j = n, j>0; j / = 2) {
                 for ( k = j, k<n; k += 2) {
                         sum + = (i + j * k);
                }
            }
          }
```

the correct answer for this code is O(n(log n)^2).
So basically it's like this right, the outer loop halves, and the middle loop increase two fold, so they are both log n, and the inner loop is N, so you times log n * log n * n. but someone told me the middle and inner loops are dependent on each other, so they should be look as one code, can someone explain it to me. But if they are one code, shouldn't I add n + log n instead multiply them? and also the outer loop are not nested so it's independent from the other two loops right?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the complexity of these three for loops?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26803976/whats-the-complexity-of-these-three-for-loops)

Comment: I went through it a bit more in-depth.

Comment: @Degustaf It's not a duplicate of that, and your answer here is most likely wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Using Sigma notation (take a look at this [document](http://faculty.kfupm.edu.sa/ics/jauhar/ics202/Unit03_ComplexityAnalysis1.ppt), slides 8, 9, and 12).

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Because both of these loops in essence do the same thing: loop `log2(n)` times, executing what's inside.

```
for ( i = 1, i<n; i * = 2) {
      for ( j = n, j>0; j / = 2) {
```

So that's how you get `O(log(N)^2)`, and because we can assume N is very large, `for ( k = j, k<n; k += 2) {` is the equivalent of N, so that becomes `O(N * log(N)^2)`

Answer (score -1):

```
for ( i = 1, i<n; i * = 2) {
```

Goes from 1, a constant, up to n, and because it's getting increased by two each time, it would be the same as for each time diving by two, which is log(n).

```
for ( j = n, j>0; j / = 2) {
```

This one starts at n and goes down until j <= 0, where 0 is a constant. Depending on what type j is, this may go on for a very long time, in fact if it was natural numbers, it would have gone on forever, because we only divide j by something, and that will always just get closer to 0, not 0 or below. I'm just going to assume it's an int, and so at 0,5 it will 0. In any case, because we go from n and divide by 2 each time, this is another log(n).

```
for ( k = j, k<n; k += 2) {
```

This where the tricky part starts, here we don't start at n or a constant. We instead start at the j from the last loop, but this can be the same as n, because j started at n. j can also be almost 0, and if we consider j to be an int, it's smallest value before 0 is 1. Therefore we can assume we start at n or 1. Which case has the most iterations? From 1 to n. Here we see that the number we start at, k, gets increased by 2 each time up to n. This really means that this will iterate n/2, but we can also say n.

Now we can multiply them together...

```
log(n)*log(n)*n = n*log(n)^2
```

We could also have said:

```
log(n)*log(n)*(n/2) = (n/2)*log(n)^2
```

Answer (score -2):

**The Complexity is O(N log(N))**

Because of the interdependency of j and k (at `k = j`) you can't consider the inner 2 loops separately. Let n=2^m, for simplicity of calculation. So, j will be 2^m, 2^(m-1), 2^(m-2), ... , 4, 2, 1, and the innermost loop executes `(n-j)/2` times each time it is reached. So the combined inner two loops execute

```
  2^m + 2^(m-1) + 2^(m-2) + ... + 4   + 2   + 1
= 2^m + 2^(m-1) + 2^(m-2) + ... + 2^2 + 2^1 + 2^0
```

This is a [Geometric Progression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression), and is equal to 2^(m+1) - 1 = 2n - 1, which is O(n). Now throwing in the outer loop, whick is O(log(N)) due to the `i *= 2`, and we get O(N log(N)).

Comment: `n^2` is greater than `n*log(n)^2`, and it's not that hard to see it is at the very least a `n*log(n)^2`.

Comment: @HorseSMith You are right.  I missed that it was `i *= 2` instead of `i++`.  I have corrected it.